# Weird casting behaviour

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism, virtual

could somebody explain the output of the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class First {
        public:
                int a;
                First() {};
                First(int a) {
                        this->a = a;
                }

                int getA() {
                        return a;
                }

                virtual int getB() {
                        cout << "getB() from super class..." << endl;
                        return 0;
                }
};

class Second : public First {
        public:
                int b;
                Second(int b) {
                        this->b = b;
                }

                int getB() {
                        cout << "getB() from child class..." << endl;
                        return b;
                }

};

int main() {
        First* t = new Second(2);
        First* cTest = dynamic_cast<First*>(t);
        cout << cTest->getB() << endl;

}
```

I expected the method of the super class would be called because of the casting to First.

thanks in advance

regards sebastian

Comment: Oh noes, 8 spaces indentation hurt my eyes

Comment: Looks like an interview question...

Comment: output is:getB() from child class...
2

Comment: You're casting First* to First*... Why do you need a cast?

Answer (score 4):

The function `getB()` is `virtual` in the base class, so you get the derived implementation no matter whether you have a pointer-to-base or pointer-to-derived.

(That's the whole purpose of polymorphism.)

Answer (score 2):

A dynamic cast up the hierarchy doesn't change the fundamental fact that you're still pointing at a B. In particular, it doesn't change the vtable used to find the implementation of getB() that will be used.

Typically, you only need dynamic_cast() to go down an inheritance hierarchy, not up.

Comment: He's not casting up the hierarchy, he's casting First* to First*.

Answer (score 1):

There only exists one object, and that is of type Second.

To get the behaviour you are looking for, you are going to have to create a copy and slice it:

```
First cTest = static_cast<First>(*t);
cout << cTest.getB() << endl;
```

Comment: It is unclear what the real need is, but it might rather be better to invoke the base class version explicitly: http://ideone.com/YD6H0

Answer (score 0):

You aren't changing anything with your cast. You are casting a First* to a First*, which is simply an assignment. Since t is a Second with `= new Second(2)`, you have overridden the virtual table with the child's entries, so it will call the child's methods rather than the parents.

cTest is simply a pointer-to-First which points to the exact same object that t does, because cTest and t contain the same memory address, at which exists a Second object, which is why the Second's method is called.

Comment: Is there a way to "really" cast it to First? So that the method of First will be used instead?

Comment: @Sebastian: after you've replaced all the virtual table entries with the derived class's methods, I don't know anyway which you can revert this. If you post your larger problem, we might be able to help you figure out a different way to solve your problem.

Comment: @Sebastian: according to DanDan below, you can dereference the pointer and static_cast that to a First object. That will work, but I strongly suggest figuring out a better way to solve whatever you are trying to solve.